# Firefox XUL call function from content context

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, overlay, xul

I know that this question was asked earlier but the OP didn't get any suitable answer.
So the question is:

> How to access page context to call some js function in FF overlay (toolbar in my case).

I have `<toolbarbutton>` element with `onclick="nextTrack()"`. `nextTrack` declared in the included JS file. Function executes when I press toolbar button, but I cannot exec function that I'm sure exists on the page.

I cannot modify the page, because it is an external site, but I really want to make my extension.

Of course I can (and I am) use something like `mainDocument.getElementById("player_play").click()`, but page already has an `audioPlayer` object that has all ability I need: `play`, `pause`, `next`, `prev` etc.

For more cleanliness I make an extension to control an audio player for vkontakte social network (well known social network in exUSSR countries). So you can look at example page here, maybe it can be helpfull: http://vk.com/wall6843477_2327.
When you start listening the bar with controls must appear you can find lot of stuff like `audioPlayer.nextTrack(); audioPlayer.prevTrack();` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't accessing content directly, you are rather going through [XPCNativeWrapper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCNativeWrapper). This means that all JavaScript properties defined by the content page are invisible (which is a security feature). In your case, the simplest secure solution is to use the `javascript:` protocol:

```js
mainDocument.defaultView.location.href = "javascript:void audioPlayer.play()";
```

This way you won't be able to get a result back but from it seems that you don't need to.

Comment: Wow! Great, how can I forgot such possibility! Thanks! But answer me one more question to understand clearly, if I'm not owner of the page (this is external site and I can't modify the page) can I interact with page script anyhow (XPCNativeWrapper I guess)?

Comment: @Luft-on: You can [use `XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(mainDocument)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCNativeWrapper#Unwrapping_an_object) and access the scripts directly - but I would recommend against it if you can avoid it. There are potential security issues here, the content scripts can react differently from what you expect and in the worst-case scenario trick your code into doing something dangerous.

Comment: Just tried this: `doc = XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(currentDocument); doc.audioPlayer.pauseTrack();` but get `Error: doc.audioPlayer is undefined`

Comment: alert(doc) gives me [Object HTMLDocument]

Comment: @Luft-on: Global variables are defined as properties of the `window` object, not the document. So it's most likely `doc.defaultView.audioPlayer`.